# Accessing programmatically created controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I've created a series of Panels within a placeholder, inside each panel is 5 textboxes.

On a button press, I want to get the .Text from each Textbox, and the ID of the Panel. I planned to use a JaggedArray to keep track of all Panels and their internal TextBoxes.

```
    string[][] jaggesaddress = new string[stop][]; //stop is an int and equal to amount of panels on screen.
    String[] numbers = new String[stop];

    int a = 0;

    //Control ctrl;

    foreach (Control ctrl in BookingPlaceholder.Controls) //BookingPlaceholder is placehodler ID
    {
        if (ctrl is Panel)
        {
            numbers[a] = ctrl.ID;
            a++;
            //ctrl.ID = numbers[a];

            foreach(TextBox tb in ctrl.ID)  // error here
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

However the second foreach loop has an error, and I am not 100% sure how to overcome this.

> "Cannot convert type 'char' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'"

I know that the numbers[a] does find the first panel, however it's a string with no extension of ID.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

- Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for more generic controls available in PlaceHolder then
you need to find textbox controls. so it is safe to check the control type also.

```
foreach (Control ctr in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (ctr is TextBox)
            {
                //Do your things
                // ((TextBox)ctr).Text 
            }
        }
```

Comment: @WillemDuncan How about this?

Comment: This is the correct way, it can even be shortened by using LINQ: `foreach(TextBox ctrl in crl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) { ... }`

Comment: yes you are right but if OP not using Linq than this is simple way.

Comment: if I write `ctr.Text` within the if i get an error that Text isn't part of Controls. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @BobbleHead This is because before using the control `ctr` directly you need to cast it as `TextBox` control. See in my edited answer.

Comment: If i search for casting what pages would you recommend reading? This is new to me.

Comment: I suggest you this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Your inner loop is trying to iterate through a string.  What you wanted was...

```
foreach(TextBox tb in ctrl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
```

instead of

```
foreach(TextBox tb in ctrl.ID)
```

Comment: `Controls` is not of type `TextBox`, this is wrong, see @Bhavesh Kachhadiya answer.